# How can I get the most recent SSL certificate for a domain using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, powershell-3.0, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to find the most recent certificate in the Web Hosting certificate store for a given domain (e.g. www.example.com)

It's easy enough to find any number of matching certificates, but how can I find only the most recent one, ordered by expiration date (furthest into the future)?

My existing code is:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting 
   | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "example.com"}).Thumbprint;
```

However this returns two certificates sometimes as usually the previous certificate (prior to a renewal) must be left in the certificate store for a short while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to sort then by the property `notafter`

To have a look to all properties :

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "example.com"}) | fl *
```

To sort by `notAfter` property :

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\ca | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match ".*microsoft.*"}) | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending
```

Comment: OK: Looks like the complete solution for me is:

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\Webhosting
 | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "example.com"}
 | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending
 | Select-Object -first 1).Thumbprint`

Answer (score 0):

Seems sorting by NotAfter will lead to issues when using Letsencrypt while you still have a 1 year valid cert expiring after the Letsencrypt cert.

Made it work by sorting with NotBefore... haven't tested much though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31507603)